# Can't catch exception in AngularFireAuth

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I try to catch exception with AngularFireAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword and show user the exists username/password error message. The exception handle code runs but somehow a similar Exception still bubbles to global error handler.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireAuth} from '@angular/fire/auth';

@Component({
  selector: 'register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.scss']
})
export class RegisterComponent {
  constructor(
    private af: AngularFireAuth,
  ) {}

  async onRegisterUsingEmailAndPassword(event) {
    const { email, password } = event;
    try {
      await this.af.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error); // <-- this code runs and logs {code: "auth/email-already-in-use", ...}
    }
  }
}
```

Using firebase.auth directly works as intended: the exception code handler runs and no exception bubbles to Global Error Handler.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

@Component({
  selector: 'register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.scss']
})
export class RegisterComponent {
  constructor() {}

  async onRegisterUsingEmailAndPassword(event) {
    const { email, password } = event;
    try {
      await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error); // <-- this code runs and logs {code: "auth/email-already-in-use", ...}
    }
  }
}
```

Dependencies:

- @angular: 10.2.4
- @angular/fire: 6.1.4
- firebase: 8.2.2

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? What did you end up doing? I'm encountering the same issue.

Comment: I've a similar issue, where in spite of my catch block, the error bubbles up to the global error handler. How do I stop that?

Comment: @user1928896 did you manage to solve this? I still have the error in the console log as a red message even though I have catches

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1881), you need to either:

1. accept the extra console errors
2. Not use async/await on firebase-js-sdk authentication methods

Answer (score -4):

You can pipe the catch to trap the error in place of the try/catch block:

```
await this.af.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(error); 
    })
```

Comment: This does not work. The catch callback will be run but the error will also bubble up to global error handler just the question happens with try/catch